# Can't seem to properly link an external java script

Tags: javascript, wamp

I am using a WAMP installation on a localhost. I am teaching myself html/javascript/ect following the tutorials on w3schools. Everything works correctly if I use the following web code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">My First Paragraph.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to move the javascript to a separate file and it just isn't working.

Contents of the HTML (in the "index" file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">My First Paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Contents of test.js

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
</script>
```

I am sure it is something silly, but after looking at a bunch of examples I can't seem to find where I am making a mistake.

Comment: put your <script src="test.js"></script> to the end of the file. just before </html>. you are trying to access element with ID demo, but html it's not fully loaded yet.

Comment: Did you try debugging the page? Open the browser's console and see what errors there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your `test.js` you **do not have to include the `<script>` tag**. That's an error, and the scripts stops because of it. Your `test.js` script should be like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
```

On the second hand, you have to put your script at the end of the body **after** the `demo` element, because if you load your script **before** it, you'll never find it.

Here is a correct solution of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>My First Web Page</h1>

       <p id="demo">My First Paragraph.</p>

       <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kestutis was right. Using yours and there suggestions everything seems to be in order. Thank you!